# Check if display is powered on

Tags: connection, monitor, vga

Is there a way to check if display is powered on in linux. I tried xrandr and xset but none of these two give me if any information about monitor power. using xrandr we can identify if the vga cable is connected but not if power is connected. I need this because many of our Lab systems keep lying unused just because some one pulls out the power cable or so.

--
Jatin

Comment: If display has no power, isn't it the same as vga cable disconnected for xrandr?

Comment: It might be best to migrate this to the relevant stackexchange network website: http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @CharlesB: It is not the same. Even if the power is off and VGA is connected it shows VGA Connected, i have been playing around with all this for past 2 days but could not figure out a way to detect monitor power off.